# pandas dictionnary of dataframes: columns get changed: view or copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have the following weird behaviour (using pandas 0.19.2, python 3.5)
If i set up a dictionary of dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b'], columns=['c1', 'c2'], data=[[0,1],[2,3]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b'], columns=['c1', 'c2'], data=[[4,5],[6,7]])

my_dict = {'f1': df1, 'f2': df2}
```

And i try to change the columns this way:

```
d = []
for key in my_dict.keys():
    df = my_dict.get(key)
    df.columns = [(key, x) for x in df.columns]
    d.append(df)
```

I end up having changed the columns of the values of the dictionary.
So `my_dict` is now:

```
{'f1':    (f1, c1)  (f1, c2)
 a         0         1
 b         2         3,
 'f2':    (f2, c1)  (f2, c2)
 a         4         5
 b         6         7}
```

Is there any reason for that?
I find it odd (and buggy) to be changing elements which have been only referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not buggy, it's just easy to miss where you created the view instead of the copy. Since you are using a dataframe in the dictionary, the following line is creating the view of your original df:

```
df = my_dict.get(key)
```

You may want to try

```
df = my_dict.get(key).copy()
```

Comment: Thanks. It's just that if I define my dictionary as  

    `my_dict = {'f1': 1, 'f2': 2}`
and i do the following

`    d = []`
`    for key in my_dict.keys():`
`        df = my_dict.get(key)`
`        df = 2`
`        d.append(df)`

then `my_dict` is unchanged.
Would you have a pointer to when a view or a copy is returned?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might find it odd (and I might agree), but it is not undocumented:

Dictionaries are mutable in python: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

> An object’s mutability is determined by its type; for instance,
> numbers, strings and tuples are immutable, while **dictionaries** and
> lists **are mutable**.
>
> Examples of containers are tuples, lists and dictionaries. The
> references are part of a container’s value. In most cases, when we
> talk about the value of a container, we imply the values, not the
> identities of the contained objects; however, when we talk about the
> mutability of a container, only the identities of the immediately
> contained objects are implied. So, **if** an immutable **container** (like a
> tuple) **contains a reference to a mutable object, its value changes if**
> **that mutable object is changed.**

Pandas dataframe are mutable:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html#mutability-and-copying-of-data

> **Mutability and copying of data**
>
> All pandas data structures are
> value-mutable (the values they contain can be altered)[...]

For instance, you could pass a dataframe as input to a function, inside the function modify the name of the columns and as an effect the dataframe outside the function will be modified as well.